# Ajuda com questão de Array em javascript [SnakeGame.js]

Tags: javascript, array, game

estou com uma duvida quanto Arrays em javascript utilizando [p5.js library](https://p5js.org/libraries/), estou querendo fazer uma cobra coral, mas para isso preciso atribuir o valor da cor para cada cada elemento da array, por exemplo:

- [primeiroElemento, cor:preto]
- [segundoElemento, cor laranja]

Como poderia fazer isso da melhor maneira?`

```
class Cobra{

    constructor(){
        //tamanho de cada parte
        this.tam = 10;
        //cores da cobra
        this.cor = [
            {_corMargin:'#FFFFFF'},
            {_corUm: '#1B1B1B'},
            {_corDois:'#FFA500'}
        ];
        //parte da cobra
        this.corpo = [
            {_x: 200, _y:200},
            {_x: 190, _y:200},
            {_x: 180, _y:200}
        ];

    }

    desenharCobra() {
        //colocarCores
        stroke(this.cor[0]._corMargin)
        fill(this.cor[1]._corUm)
        
        //colocar corpo pra c/array
        function desenharCorpo(parte){
            rect(parte._x, parte._y,10,10)
        }

        this.corpo.forEach(desenharCorpo)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui,executei o próprio parâmetro do methodo forEach que verifica o index.

```
class Cobra {
constructor(){
    this.corpo = {
        cores: ['black','orange'],
        tamanho: 10,
        posicao: [
            {_x: 50, _y:200},
            {_x: 40, _y:200},
            {_x: 30, _y:200},
            {_x: 20, _y:200}
        ]
    }
    this.cauda = []
    this.cabecaCobra = this.corpo.posicao[0]; 
}
desenhoCobra(){
    this.corpo.posicao.forEach(
        function (pos,lugar){
            rect(pos._x, pos._y, 10, 10)
            if (lugar % 2){
                console.log('par')
                fill('black')
            }else{
                console.log('impar')
                fill('orange')
            }
        },
    );
    
}
```

}